# How can I dynamically set the image size ratio depending on the returned image in raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

How can I dynamically set the image size ratio depending on the returned image in raphael?

Here is some code to give you an idea:

```
var viewer = Raphael(0,0,scrWidth, scrHeight);
viewer.image(dynamicUrl, 140, 140,300, scaledHeight);
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you trying to scale the image while retaining its aspect ratio? Or are you trying to query the returned image for its aspect ratio, and then do something with that information?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to add the image to the paper scaled correctly. i'll update the example hopefully that will make it clearer. thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the image outside the DOM and get its dimensions... You can put this inside a function:

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = dynamicUrl;
myImg.onload = function() {
    var width = myImg.width;
    var height = myImg.height;
    var scale = 0.5; // for example

    var viewer = Raphael(0,0,width, height);  // or whatever other size
    viewer.image(dynamicUrl, 0, 0, width*scale, height*scale); // scale image
        // after the image is in the viewer you can use .scale()
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SHEAr/)

Now you can divide or multiply both `width` and `height` to scale. Make sure you pay attention to the timing.

Also, once the image is in Raphael, you can use **[`.scale()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#scale)**

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I would need to use the DOM to do this.

Comment: @DaveTaylor this is a typical javascript characteristic. you have no access to file porperties or anything else in the filessystem instead of html5 drag and drop or so